# The difference between Talend Open Studio for data integration and Open Studio for ESB

Tags: talend

I would like to know the difference between Talend Open Studio for data integration and Open Studio for ESB ?
If there is a difference when we have to use each of them ?

Comment: If you know [data integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integration) and [esb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) you will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talend Open Studio for ESB basically contains the "Data Integration" studio in its 'Integration' Perspective. So you have access to the whole Data Integration Studio in the ESB Studio.

The ESB studio adds several functions :

- in the 'Integration' perspective, you'll find a 'Service' tab in the repository, giving you the possibility to create SOAP services, by creating or importing a WSDL file.
- In the 'Integration' perspective, you'll have access to some more components (tESB* components, tRestRequest/tRestResponse)
- You have a new 'Mediation' perspective, which is completely new : you can create Routes with it, using camel-based components (see http://camel.apache.org/ ). 
  Thoses routes are event-driven and need an OSGI container (like the embedded Karaf) to run.

ESB could be the right studio to use if :

- you are interested in producing webservices
- you are interested in routing/messaging (mediation perspective) using camel components.

PS : it seems that since Studio 6.2, Mediation and Integration perspectives have been merged. I have not worked with this version for now.

Hope this helps.